# greping multiple lines from MySql binlog

Tags: logging, mysql-replication, grep, pcre

I have binlog from MySQL and I need to output certain time frame into a seperate file, how would I do that?

here is sample of what binlog file contains:

```
# at 460
#130120  0:09:17 server id 1  end_log_pos 487   Xid = 79514636
COMMIT/*!*/;
# at 487
#130120  0:09:17 server id 1  end_log_pos 560   Query   thread_id=248447    exec_time=0 error_code=0
```

I'm looking to grep following:

```
#130120  0:09:17 server id 1  end_log_pos 487   Xid = 79514636
COMMIT/*!*/;
# at 487
```

I've tried `pcregrep -M`, but so far without any luck, my regex skills isn't where I thought they are, here is my actual line:

```
# mysqlbinlog /var/lib/mysql/log/logbin/mysql-bin.001036 | pcregrep -M '130120(\n|.*)\ at\ '
#
```

*** UPDATE ***

- number of lines between varies between different queries.

*** UPDATE 2 ***

this actually did the job...

```
# mysqlbinlog /var/lib/mysql/log/logbin/mysql-bin.001036 | sed -e '/130120 13/,/ at /!d' > /tmp/13
#
```

Comment: What information do you wish to find - your example appears to show 2 entries at 09:17 what distinguishes the two ?

Comment: I need to grep/grab all queries that were made from 11:30 13:30 and put that into a separate file, this is just an example of what binlog looks like, i don't want to post my actual data...

Comment: Is the snippet from the log 9 minutes and 17 seconds past midnight ? What does the time look like at 13:30 ?

Comment: kinda sounds like a job for `awk` to me.

Comment: @Iain yeah, it says `#130120 13:30`

Comment: @Zoredache: and me too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer is to use the command line options to `mysqlbinlog`

`mysqlbinlog --start-datetime=datetime --stop-datetime=datetime /path/to/mysql-bin.001036`

Answer (score 1):

This could have been done with `awk` very easily.

E.g

```
mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.001 | awk '($1 == "130120") {print $0}' > results.txt
```

This is tells `awk` to find anything in the first column that matches  `130120` *exactly* and then print that entire line.

If you needed the minute *and* second *exactly*, you could then do something like the following:

```
awk '(($1 == "130120") && ($2 == "0:09:17")) {print $0}'
```

If you *just* needed the minute, you could use something like this:

```
awk '(($1 == "130120") && ($2 ~ "^0:09:")) {print $0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

this did the job:

```
# mysqlbinlog /var/lib/mysql/log/logbin/mysql-bin.001036 | sed -e '/130120 13/,/ at /!d' > /tmp/13
#
```

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -C 1 COMMIT filename
```

-C is context, 1 line before and 1 line after

-A is after

-B is before

Comment: please see my update.